# How to changed button color at runtime using collection in wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf

Student:

```
public class Student
{
    private int _studentNo;
    public int StudentNo
    {
        get { return _studentNo; }
        set { _studentNo = value; }
    }

    private Rank _state;
    public Rank State
    {
        get { return _state; }
        set { _state = value; }
    }
}
```

Rank:

```
public enum Rank
{
    Pass,
    Fail
}
```

RankBoard:

```
public class RankBoard:BindableBase
{

    private static ObservableCollection<Student> _studentList;
    public static ObservableCollection<Student> StudentList
    {
        get { return _studentList; }
        set
        {
            _studentList = value;

        }
    }

    static RankBoard()
    {
        LoadDetails();
    }

    private static void LoadDetails()
    {
        StudentList = new ObservableCollection<Student>()
        {
            new Student()
            {
                StudentNo=1,
                State=Rank.Pass
            },
            new Student()
            {
                StudentNo=2,
                State=Rank.Fail
            },
            new Student()
            {
                StudentNo=3,
                State=Rank.Pass
            },
        };
    }

    public void ColorChanged(Student Items)
    {
        Student temp= _studentList.Where(i => i.StudentNo == Items.StudentNo).Single();
        StudentList.Remove(temp);
        StudentList.Add(Items);
    }
}
```

BindableBase:

```
public class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
    }
}
```

BackgroundChange:

```
public class BackgroundChange : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var b = value as Button;
        if(b!=null)
        {
            foreach (var x in RankBoard.StudentList.Where(i=>i.StudentNo==System.Convert.ToInt32(b.Content)))
            {
                if ((x.State.ToString()=="Pass"))
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
                }
                else
                {
                    return new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                }
            }
        }
        return null;

    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Mainwindow.xaml

```
    <Window x:Class="ButtonColorChanged.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ButtonColorChanged"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Window.Resources>
    <local:BackgroundChange x:Key="Color"/>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0 30 0 0"> 
        <TextBox x:Name="txt1" Width="75" Height="25"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt2" Width="75" Height="25" Margin="20 0 20 0"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnadd" Width="75" Height="25" Content="Add" Click="btnadd_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button x:Name="btn1" Content="1" Width="75" Height="25" Background="{Binding ElementName=btn1,Converter={StaticResource Color}}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn2" Content="2" Width="75" Height="25" Margin="0 20 0 20" Background="{Binding ElementName=btn2,Converter={StaticResource Color}}"/>
        <Button x:Name="btn3" Content="3" Width="75" Height="25" Background="{Binding ElementName=btn3,Converter={StaticResource Color}}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

I want to change button color at runtime if i change the collection of the data.
but if i put dynamicresource, exception will throw. so how do i do?

Comment: Using `Color` and not `SolidColorBrush`

Comment: DynamicResource Not needed?

Comment: You can use your StaticRessource with IValueConverter if you want. You can also define a property in your model which calculates the color and bind it to the button background if you want.

Comment: How do i define a property?may u tell sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Binding:

```
<Button x:Name="btn1" Content="1" Width="75" Height="25" Background="{Binding Path=ButtonColor}"/>
```

Your class:

```
public class RankBoard : BindableBase
{
    private Color _buttonColor;
    public Color ButtonColor 
    {
        get
        {
            return _buttonColor;
        }
        set
        {
            _buttonColor = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ButtonColor");
        }
    }

    public void RefreshButtonColor(int content)
    {
        foreach (var x in StudentList.Where(i=>i.StudentNo==content))
        {
            if ((x.State.ToString()=="Pass"))
            {
                ButtonColor = Colors.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                ButtonColor = Colors.Red;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Call `RefreshButtonColor` whenever you want to change the color of the buttons according to the student list.

When I look at your code, you want to change the color for all button according to their content. If you use properties you have to define properties for each button. And in `RefreshButtonColor` you have to choose which property you want to update according to the input. This is just an example of how to change button color.

Comment: show error b.content in RefreshButtonColor() method.? what i do..?